# Search through .zst text files

Tags: ack, ag, zstd

I have large zstd-compressed text files.

How can I run fast search over them ?

Can I use AG (The Silver Searcher) or something similar ?

I've tried AG but it doesn't work, I have a "failed to load error" :

```sh
ag -z -i "term"
```

Answer (score 15):

Use `zstdgrep`.

It is like grep, but for searching through zstd-compressed files.